# Link a cell to call a different ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I am new to Swift (I use 2.0) and haven't any programmed experience. So, I'm new ) trying to do something fairly simple. Link a `UITableViewCell` click to call a different `ViewController`. It's like user click on cell Cars and open new `ViewController`.

I have created `ViewControllers (storyboard A,B,C,D,E)`.
How I can connect? If I correctly understood I should use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Code which I have done:

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


let list = ["Cars", "Fruits", "Foods", "Toys"]
let listdesc = ["Toyota", "Apple", "Meat", "Fallout 4"]
let identities = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return list.count;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier: String = "cell"

    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)

    cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = listdesc[indexPath.row]

    return cell

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have to do in this way in didSelectRowForIndexPath:

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

       let StoryBoard  = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

      if(list[indexPath.row] == "Cars") {
         var vcA = STORYBOARD.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("A") as! A
         self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vcA, animated: true)
      } else if(list[indexPath.row] == "Fruits") {
          var vcB = STORYBOARD.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("B") as! B
          self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vcB, animated: true)
      }

  }
```

and other condition you will manage as I show....

Comment: for that he should set `stoaryboard identifier`! You should mentioned that in answer!

Comment: Thanks everybody, I really appreciate. I have 2 critical errors with as! A and as! B -> Use of undeclared type "A" and "B". Please check my storyboard - https://postimg.org/image/altu24893/

Answer (score 0):

As answered by Gaurav, you can check in didSelectRowAtIndexPath that which indexPath is selected and then navigate to that respective controller.

But if you are using different storyboards then self.storyboard instead of STORYBOARD may come in handy.

Also change the objects of your viewController from var to let as you are not changing them so they should be constants.

And the last one "Always avoid force unwrapping", handle the error yourself instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to prepare data something like this and

```
 options =    [
      {
        "category":"Cars"
        "subcat":"Cars"
        "viewType":"A"
      },
    {
        "category":"Fruits"
        "subcat":"Apple"
        "viewType":"B"
      },{
        "category":"Foods"
        "subcat":"Meat"
        "viewType":"C"
      }
    ]
```

It's not exactly copy paste answer for you, but you need to create a data like data. 
You need to modify data all together so for particular index with in single dictionary object you will get all data at once. If as your array will not have proper data then you app may crash if index will will not proper.

Then for particular index you can get viewType. you can compare it with required type and get the viewcontroller reference and push it.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

      if(options[indexPath.row]["viewType"] == "A") {
        // Get A controller reference and use it
       }else if(options[indexPath.row]["viewType"] == "B") {
        // Get A controller reference and use it
       }else if(options[indexPath.row]["viewType"] == "C") {
        // Get A controller reference and use it
       }
  }
```

I hope you will understand the structure. Please, let me know if you are not clear.

Updated:
To get reference from storyboard,

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "someViewController") as! UIViewController
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks, it's really clear. But, how I can "Get A controller reference and use it"? I am really new in swift.

Comment: I have added few line just check.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


        // If storyboard name is A.storyboard.
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "A", bundle: nil)  
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("nextViewControllerId") as! nextViewController // The `nextViewController` storyboardId is supposed as "nextViewControllerId"
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

This will present `nextViewController` every time you click any cell. If you want specific cell to open different viewcontroller use you logic using conditions within this function.

Answer (score 0):

*1. Create a segue from TableViewController Scene to other
    ViewControllerScene.*

*2. Give unique identifier to each scene.*

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //Based on your condition.
    //Initiates the segue with the specified identifier from the current view controller's storyboard file.
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueA", sender: self)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have three storyboard like Main, PreLogin and PostLogin. Then you declare first all storyboard like this:-

```
 let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 let preLoginStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "PreLogin", bundle: nil)
 let postLoginStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "PostLogin", bundle: nil)
```

You call different viewController from the     didSelectRowAtIndexPath method like that:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    switch indexPath.row{
        case 0:
            let firstViewControllerScene = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("firstViewControllerId") as! FirstViewController 
            self.presentViewController(firstViewControllerScene, animated: true)

        case 1:
            let secondViewControllerScene = preLoginStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("secondViewControllerId") as! SecondViewController 
            self.presentViewController(secondViewControllerScene, animated: true)

        case 2:
            let thirdViewControllerScene = postLoginStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("thirdViewControllerId") as! ThirdViewController 
            self.presentViewController(thirdViewControllerScene, animated: true)

        default:
           break
      }     
 }
```